How can I create flashlight cursor effect in Delphi?
For example this screenshot belongs to Daemon Tools (which is programmed in C#):

As you can see in this screenshot, I want to create flashlight effect which follows cursor.
How can I do this in Delphi with VCL framework?

I actually made a button control with such an effect some ten years ago. Here's the source code: http://privat.rejbrand.se/asbutton2.html. Here's a compiled EXE demo: http://privat.rejbrand.se/asbutton.exe. Sample video: http://privat.rejbrand.se/asbutton2.mp4. Consider the source code of this particular unit, asbutton2.pas, PD.

Btw, what does this have to do with smartphone flashlights?

(Actually, it's 15 years old. Time flies.)

@AndreasRejbrand very interesting. You are skilled! Do you have the referenced units available as well (if they are needed) ?

@AndreasRejbrand In order to use Asbutton2.pas, you should share RejbrandCommon.pas and RejbrandMessages.pas.

@ÇağatayKAYA: These units only contain standard utility functions like RGB to HSV conversion, which can be accomplished in other ways. I just shared the unit for educational purposes; all interesting parts of the code are self-contained in the unit. However, for your convenience, I made a quick attempt to make the unit fully self-contained so it can be used and compiled immediately: http://privat.rejbrand.se/asbutton2e.html. You can consider this one PD too.
